# Nginx Redirecting

Tags: nginx, url

I have spent a couple of days trying to trouble shoot this problem to no avail. I am trying to use Nginx to send different URLS to different docker containers.

my config file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 8000;

        server_name  myserver.com www.myserver.com ;

        location /api/wtrsbnd_10m {
            proxy_set_header Host localhost;
            rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass         http://backend:8000;
        }


        location /api/fzs_cb10m {
            proxy_set_header Host localhost;
            rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass        http://fzs_cb10m:8000;
        }


        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://frontend:3000/;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I send 
http://myserver.com/api/fzs_cb10m/ 
It always redirects to the correct machine http://fzs_cb10m:8000;

But when I send 
http://myserver.com/api/wtrsbnd_10m/ it redirects to http://fzs_cb10m:8000 1/2 of the time and http://backend:8000 the other half of the time. I need it to always redirect to http://backend:8000

Comment: The configuration itself seems like it should work (at a glance at least), are you certain the issue isn't on the backends? Could you maybe illustrate your issue using curl and provide the output?

Comment: Please do a `curl -I http://myserver.com/api/wtrsbnd_10m/` and add the output to your question, so we can have a look at it.